# Adding a new column for each existing one in data frame (for outlier detection)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df. For each column I want to add another column indicating whether the value is inside or outside my simple "outlier detection thresholds" by writing TRUE (= outlier) or FALSE (= no outlier).

Here's the code:

```
df <- read.csv("<FILE>", header=TRUE, sep=";")
column_names <- colnames(df[,-1])  # first column is actually row name

for(name in column_names) {  
  med <- median(df[[name]], na.rm = TRUE)
  std <- sd(df[[name]], na.rm = TRUE)
  max <- med + 3 * std
  min <- med - 3 * std

  newcol <- paste(name, "outlier", sep="_")  # create new column name
  df <- within(df, newcol <- ifelse(name < max & name > min,"FALSE","TRUE"))
}
```

Instead of adding a new column for every existing one, just one column named "newcol" is added. How do I access the actual value of the variable newcol in this case? Alread tried get(newcol) and [[newcol]].

Thank you so much for your help!

EDIT:
Solution looks like this

```
df <- read.csv("<FILE>", header=TRUE, sep=";")
column_names <- colnames(df[,-1])  # first column is actually row name
for(name in column_names) {
  med <- median(df[[name]], na.rm = TRUE)
  std <- sd(df[[name]], na.rm = TRUE)
  max <- med + 3 * std
  min <- med - 3 * std

  newcol <- paste(name, "outlier", sep="_")
  df[[newcol]] <- with(df, ifelse(df[[name]] < max & df[[name]] > min,"FALSE","TRUE"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line should read:

```
df[[newcol]] <- with(df, ifelse(...))
```

The `<-` operator assumes that `newcol` is the actual name of the column, not a variable that contains this name.

Comment: sorry, figured it out. Added the solution to my initial question.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @chrmar You should not edit questions to include answers. If you have a different answers, post it as a solution so the community may upvote/downvote for future users that stumble across this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach using `data.table`

```
require(data.table)

outlier <- function(x) {
  med <- median(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  std <- sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  max <- med + 3 * std
  min <- med - 3 * std
  return(!(x < max & x > min))
}

# df <- fread("<FILE>")
df <- data.table(x = rt(10, 5), y = rt(10, 5))
df[3, x := 100]
df[7, y := 100]

df[, paste(names(df), "outlier", sep="_") := lapply(.SD, outlier)]
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign everything at once:

```
is_outlier <- function(x) {
    med <- median(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    std <- sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    max <- med + 3 * std
    min <- med - 3 * std
    !(x < max & x > min)
}

column_names <- names(df)[-1]
column_names_outlier <- paste(column_names, "outlier", sep="_")
df[column_names_outlier] <- lapply(df[column_names], is_outlier)
```